# How to display external XML in an HTML file

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XML file styled with external XSL file, but when I specify the path to it in HTML body tag, it doesn't display the data,  just a blank page. Is there something else that needs to be done?

Basically what I've done in html is this:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <xml id="asdfgh" src="asdfgh.xml"></xml>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just load `asdfgh.xml` into the web browser directly? If by "styled with external XSL file" you intend to say that the XML file contains an `<?xsl-stylesheet?>` pseudo-instruction, then this is something that is applied when the XML file is loaded in the browser, not when an `<xml>` tag is found lurking within the HTML.

Answer (score 5):

try using an good old iframe:

```
<iframe id="asdfgh" src="asdfgh.xml"></iframe>
```

Comment: that's probably due to you opening the html in FF or Chrome via file protocol and the browser refusing to take the content from there. Check the console of your browser or try it in IE.

Answer (score 0):

xml tags are often ignored by browsers on HTML documents, in best cases they will only show the inner text. If you need to show the whole code you will need some XSLT to transform the XML into HTML or event a Javascript program that prints it. Maybe this one http://www.levmuchnik.net/Content/ProgrammingTips/WEB/XMLDisplay/DisplayXMLFileWithJavascript.html

Comment: But the XML file already has an XSL file using XSL transform binded to it.

Comment: do you have an XML and a XSL local files to transform?

Comment: Yes, the files are local, if that's what you're asking.